# Función devuelve clase con valores cuando no debería

Tags: c#

Anteriormente había realizado una pregunta sobre el siguiente código, acabé borrando la pregunta dado que no estaba bien formulada.

Haciendo debug a mi aplicación me he percatado de que mi función devuelve una clase con valores cuando no debería dado que el IF es falso, como mucho debería devolverme la clase con sus parametros por defecto, pero, tiene los valores de **stockAvailableOrigen**.

Únicamente tengo problemas con la función **BuscaStockOrigen**, dado que la función **BuscaStockDestino**
me devuelve la clase que corresponde cuando el IF es true o false.

¿Qué ocurre?
Adjunto imagen.

```
    private stock_available BuscaStockOrigen(product productoOrigen, List<stock_available> stocksAvailableOrigen)
    {
        stock_available stock = new stock_available();
        foreach (var stockAvailableOrigen in stocksAvailableOrigen)
        {
            if (productoOrigen.id == stockAvailableOrigen.id_product)
            {
                stock = stockAvailableOrigen;
            }
        }
        return stock;
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2eKs.png

PREGUNTA EDITADA=>

Acabo de revisar el código y cuando se cumple la condición IF, y se le asigna a **stock** el contenido de **stockAvailableOrigen**, hasta ahí bien, pero, cuando sale del IF y del FOREACH, en el return el valor de stock cambia.

Comment: Estás retornando un objeto stock de la clase stock_available, tal vez cuando lo inicializas, por ahí le agregas algún valor por default.

Comment: Al crear la clase stock_available, sus propiedades son : id=null, id_product=null, quantity=0. Por lo que no entiendo por que cuando devuelvo la clase, toma los valores de stockAvailableOrigen si no se cumple la condicion en el momento del punto de interrupción que puse en la linea 'return stock;'

Comment: O sea.. tu solucion de hace un rato no soluciono nada??? ;)

Comment: no... voy a actualizar la pregunta con lo que acabo de ver con el debug de visual studio, a ver si se os ocurre algo.

Comment: HAce un [mcve]. Vuelvo a decir lo que dije antes.. el if no anda mal en .net (si no todos estariamos en serios problemas), aca hay algo de tu logica que no estas viendo correctamente...

Comment: en el return el valor no cambia. no hay algo magico que pase ahi. Algo, en otro lado, te esta dando otro valor y no es el que vos pensas. hace lo que te dije (un [mcve]) y vas a ver que es asi...

Answer (score 0):

Al final, la condición del IF se cumplía más de una vez (me lo dijeron en la anterior pregunta), por lo que cada vez que salia del IF y pasaba al FOREACH, los valores cambiaban y se hacía RETURN del último 'stock'.
:')

Comment: pero... no es lo que estabas preguntando... vos preguntaste porque al no cumplirse el if, devolvia otra cosa.. Te recomendaria que leyeras [ask]... y trata de seguir las recomendaciones que te dan siempre...

Comment: El problema era que estaba dando por sentado que el IF solo se cumplia 1 vez. Por eso el valor de STOCK se sustituía cuando salía del IF.

Comment: Lo leeré con detenimiento, me pasa por no fijarme ni saber explicarme correctamente. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: lo del valor, lo deberias haber notado al hacer la depuracion... si entraba mas de una vez en la condicion, entonces el valor iba a ser el ultimo...